# How do I get npm to run in terminal?

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal

I'm tasked with creating a simple calculator application for entry to a programming course. I'm having issues with Terminal :(

I'm not looking for an answer to my overall task, I just want to know why Terminal wont RUN!! What am I doing wrong?

Steps as follows:

Create a directory that you will keep your Calculator application in. Call it
something sensible, like "Calculator".

Open up a command prompt and navigate to your calculator directory 
**Run npm init to create a new Node.js project. Use the default answer to every
question it asks you (just press "Enter") - don't worry if you don't understand
what all the questions mean!
If it doesn't do anything after the final question "Is this ok?", double-check
there's a file in the folder called package.json . If it's there, everything went
smoothly and you can exit the npm init process by typing in the console
Ctrl + C .**

So my problem is... when I run npm, all that happens is my Mac asks if Terminal can access or change files in my system, I click yes, then Terminal doesn't do anything from there, no questions etc I just get:

I can't see **package.json**, so I take it it hasn't worked properly? How can I fix this to move on?

I'm using zsh on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off. What ide do you use? (Personally I like Visual Studio Code).
I'm not sure what the short command is for you to open up the terminal but just google it. Otherwise, you can click "Terminal" on the very top and open a new terminal.

When you do this, you will get a new window at the bottom of your screen. This window has some tabs, make sure you are in the terminal tab.
While there, type "npm init".

This will give you your package.json-file.

If you want to use your terminal for outputs I recommend you get nodejs too.